# create swf from a decompiled swf file

Tags: flash, swf-decompiler

My client gave me a swf file to modify that. I use showmycode.com and decompile that swf, get some action script codes like these

```
//package { import flash.display.*; public dynamic class video_play_btn extends SimpleButton { } }//package package { import flash.display.*; public dynamic class ScrollArrowDown_upSkin extends movieclip { } }//package package { import flash.display.*; public dynamic class TextInput_disabledSkin extends movieclip { } }
```

I want to create a swf file from this codes? Do I create a .fla file or a .as file?

Answer (score 0):

It's almost impossible to create a swf from this code. To do that, you should reconstruct all MovieClips on Stage and put parts of this code in proper places, for example:

```
public dynamic class Symbol5_3 extends movieclip {
   // code here, should be placed in first frame of Symbol5_3 movieclip.
}
```